# Cannot conditionally render component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webcam, mediapipe

I have a problem with my React app: I need to conditionally render a Button on screen when a certain variable (`repetitions`) exceeds a threshold.

The variable is updated into the `componentDidMount()` function, which retrieves the video from webcam and updates the abovementioned variable depending on what it retrieves on the video:

```js
export default class Recognizer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      repetitions : 0,
      max_repetitions : 15
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName('input_video')[0];
    const canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName('output_canvas')[0];
    const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');

    function onResults(results) {
      canvasCtx.save();
      canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
      canvasCtx.drawImage(results.image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
      
      var point;
      var sample = [];

      for (point = 0; point < results.poseLandmarks.length; point++) {
         sample.push(results.poseLandmarks[point].x*canvasElement.width)
         sample.push(results.poseLandmarks[point].y*canvasElement.width)
         sample.push(results.poseLandmarks[point].z*canvasElement.width)
        }

      let result=predict(sample) //some kind on ML in "predict" function 
      
      if (result==1) {
         repetitions=repetitions+1 // <-- I should update this.state.repetitions here but I cannot access "this"
        }

      canvasCtx.restore();
    }

    const pose = new Pose({locateFile: (file) => {
      return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/pose@0.3.1620325689/${file}`;
    }});
    pose.onResults(onResults);

    const camera = new Camera(videoElement, {
      onFrame: async () => {
        await pose.send({image: videoElement});
      },
      width: 1280,
      height: 720
    });
    camera.start();

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Home">
        <div className="lander">

        <div className="App">
            <video hidden className="input_video"></video>
            <canvas className="output_canvas" width="1280px" height="720px"></canvas>
        </div>
        
        {this.state.repetitions > this.state.max_repetitions ? <form><Button className="btn-action">Continue</Button></form>: null }
  
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see in the code, there is a `onResults` function into `componentDidMount()` is there a way to access the state variables from there?

Thank you.

Comment: can you try after making `onResults` as arrow function like `const onResults = (results) => { ... }`

Comment: You can create a variable storing `this` value like `const context = this` above the onResults declaration. and inside the function use `context.setState()` to update state

Comment: changing `onResult` to arrow function worked! Thank you very much!